# with which binary action is the 2-sphere a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups

show that the 2-sphere is a Lie group.
I do not know with which binary action is the 2-sphere a Lie group? and with which binary action  is the $\mathbb{R^3}-{0}$ a Lie group?

2-sphere is equal with $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}; x^2 +y^2+ z^2 =1 \}$

Comment: s-sphere means the 2-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: See for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/809830/11619) or the highest rated *Related* question on the list on the right margin.

Comment: The spheres $S^n$ with their standard smooth structure are Lie groups only in dimensions $1$ and $3$, $S^2$ is not a Lie group under any binary operation.

Comment: Why? Can you introduce a reference for your answer?Is the $\mathbb{R}^3−\{0\}$ a lie group?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ is not a Lie group either. The reason for $S^2$ is that if it were a Lie group, you could take a tangent vector $v$ in $T_e S^2$ (the tangent space in the identity element) left multiplication $L_g: x\mapsto g\cdot x$ would take it to a nonzero vector $(L_g)_∗(v)$ in the tangent space of any element $g$. But there doesn't exists a continuous nowhere zero vector fields on $S^2$, see the Hairy ball theorem.

Comment: The reference to Hairy ball theorem is for example in Milnor, Topology from differentiable viewpoint, Chapt. 6, or Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, Thm 2.28. The fact that $S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only Lie group spheres is harder. You might have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/is-there-an-easy-way-to-show-which-spheres-can-be-lie-groups)..

Comment: ..to be honest, I don't know how to prove the $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ case. Would be interested, if somebody more experienced comments..